# start a command line executable without a flash command window show

Tags: c#, .net

Can I start another process in the same command line window?

I have use StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

It seems it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to redirect the console output of the new process to the console output of the current process (Console.WriteLine etc.) 

e.g.:

 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/edwinlima/SystemDiagnosticProcess12052005035444AM/SystemDiagnosticProcess.aspx